# Truncate string to max limit during JaxB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a requirement to truncate the size of string in the XML if the string size exceeds the max size defined in XSD. Is there a way in JAXB where we can truncate the strings on marshalling directly, instead of manual verification of each property in  object and truncating the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html

Something like this:

```
public class TruncatorAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
    Integer maxLen=...;
    /*Java => XML*/
    public String marshal(String val) throws Exception {
        return val.substring(0,maxLen);
    }
    /*XML => Java*/
    public String unmarshal(String val) throws Exception {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in this case the max length is fixed and is not dynamic right?? i cannot use this across multiple strings with different max length values?

Comment: A simple solution is implement different class with different length.

public class TruncatorAdapter10 extends TruncatorAdapter {
    public TruncatorAdapter10 (){
        super(10);
    }
}

ecc...